# How to return only unique values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique

```
SELECT users.mail, users.name FROM members
LEFT JOIN users ON (users.uid = members.uid) WHERE members.group = 27
AND members.uid NOT IN (SELECT subgroup_members.uid FROM subgroup_members
LEFT JOIN subgroups ON (subgroups.id = subgroup_members.sid)
LEFT JOIN users on (users.uid = subgroup_members.uid) WHERE subgroups.oid = 27 AND subgroup_members.leader = 1)
```

This query returns all members of a group that are not leaders of a subgroup.

The members table shows which `userid(uid)` belong to a `group(group)`, and the `subgroup_members` table shows which users belong to a `subgroup(sid)`. Leadership is denoted by '1' in the leader column of the subgroup_members table.

I am trying to figure out how to return all members of a group that are not the *only* leader of a subgroup and I am pretty stumped right now.

So instead of `subgroup_members.leader = 1` I need to determine if it's the only value

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `GROUP BY` to isolate unique indices.

**Documentation**: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html